# How to get the total of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/2) here at SQL Fiddle.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  Shot VARCHAR(4),
  sec varchar(5),
  lay VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  lay_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  blk VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  blk_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  pri VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  pri_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  ani VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  ani_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'SH01','3','1863','yes','1863','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','Over'),
(2,'SH02','2.5','1863','yes','P4645','no','P4557','yes','1863','no','Over'),
(3,'SH03','0.5','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','1863','yes','1863','yes','WIP'),
(4,'SH04','1.25','1863','no','P4645','no','P4557','yes','1863','yes','RTK'),
(5,'SH05','1','1863','yes','1863','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','WIP'),
(6,'SH06','6','P4557','yes','P4645','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','WIP');
```

I used below SQL to retrieve Shots of `lay=1863`. and get the total at the bottom of the seconds.

Bu the result is wrong. Can anyone guide me.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
  , sec
  , lay
FROM my_table
where lay='1863'
group by shot with rollup;
```

The result in the total (for sec column) should be 7.75, now its showing 1

```
SHOT    SEC     LAY
SH01    3       1863
SH02    2.5     1863
SH04    1.25    1863
SH05    1       1863
TOTAL   7.75
```

Comment: what u mean wrong ? what result you want ?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using a `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function. In your current query you are not using `sum()` on the `sec` column which is the column you want to rollup. Try using:

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
  , sum(sec) Sec
  , min(lay) lay
FROM my_table
where lay='1863'
group by shot with rollup;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/37).

Your current query is not performing any aggregation so the final rollup row is not correct.

- MySQL Docs [`GROUP BY` modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

You will notice that I placed the `lay` column in an aggregate function.  This is because most database products do not allow columns in the select list to be excluded from being inside of an aggregate function or being included in a `group by`.

MySQL allows this because an [Extension to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Edit: If you want to hide the result in the `lay` column for the last row, then you can use:

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
  , sum(sec) Sec
  , case when shot is not null then min(lay) else '' end lay
FROM my_table
where lay='1863'
group by shot with rollup;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/60)

Comment: UI dont think we need min(lay) lay. Can you tell me why you used it. ant how thanks for the answer, as i learned new function `coalesce`

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao MySQL does not require it to be in an aggregate but I added the aggregation so this query will work outside of MySQL. :)

Comment: In the last row last column (lay) beside 7.75 it is displaying 1863. which i dont want to display. can you tell how to avoid it.

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao See my latest edit or this demo --http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/60

Answer (score 3):

As you want the sum use this query

```
SELECT 
  Shot
  , sum(sec)
FROM my_table
where lay='1863'
group by shot with rollup;
```

The GROUP BY clause permits a WITH ROLLUP modifier that causes extra rows to be added to the summary output. These rows represent higher-level (or super-aggregate) summary operations

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY is for aggregates, if you want the sum of sec you have to ask for the sum.

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
    , sum(sec)
    , max(lay)
    FROM my_table
    WHERE lay='1863'
    GROUP BY shot WITH ROLLUP;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/49

Comment: In the last row last column (lay) beside 7.75 it is displaying 1863. which i dont want to display. can you tell how to avoid it.

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao replace `max(lay)` with `(CASE WHEN shot IS NOT NULL THEN max(lay) ELSE '' END)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  SELECT 
  IFNULL(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
 , sum(sec) as sec
 , lay
 FROM my_table
 where lay='1863'
 group by shot with rollup;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/47)

**EDIT**
you may consider to count how many rows in TOTAL  because total maybe you will count also how much fields there is .  like that

```
 SELECT 
 IFNULL(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
 , sum(sec) as sec
 , if(Shot is null , count(*) , lay) lay
 FROM my_table
 where lay='1863'
 group by shot with rollup;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f61b/76)

and if you want to be empty just replace `count(*)` by `''`

Comment: In the last row last column (lay) beside 7.75 it is displaying 1863. which i dont want to display. can you tell how to avoid it.

Comment: because i think its better if you count also how many fields in TOTAL .

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is a list of MySQL built in functions for the group by aggregate

```
AVG() Return the average value of the argument
BIT_AND() Return bitwise and
BIT_OR()  Return bitwise or
BIT_XOR()(v4.1.1) Return bitwise xor
COUNT(DISTINCT)   Return the count of a number of different values
COUNT()   Return a count of the number of rows returned
GROUP_CONCAT()(v4.1)  Return a concatenated string
MAX() Return the maximum value
MIN() Return the minimum value
STD() Return the population standard deviation
STDDEV_POP()(v5.0.3)  Return the population standard deviation
STDDEV_SAMP()(v5.0.3) Return the sample standard deviation
STDDEV()  Return the population standard deviation
SUM() Return the sum
VAR_POP()(v5.0.3) Return the population standard variance
VAR_SAMP()(v5.0.3)    Return the sample variance
VARIANCE()(v4.1)  Return the population standard variance
```

I believe that you want SUM()

try

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
,SUM(sec) AS sec 
, lay
FROM my_table
where lay='1863'
group by shot with rollup;
```

Comment: In the last row last column (lay) beside 7.75 it is displaying 1863. which i dont want to display. can you tell how to avoid it.

Comment: Try it

SELECT 
  coalesce(Shot,'TOTAL') AS Shot
  , sum(sec) Sec
  , case when shot is not null then min(lay) else '' end lay
FROM my_table
where lay='1863'
group by shot with rollup;

Answer (score 1):

At all it looks not correct to use 'lay' column for TOTAL row. Excepting that here is SQL which will give you expected result:

```
SELECT Shot, sec, lay FROM my_table WHERE lay = '1863'
UNION
SELECT 'TOTAL' AS Shot, SUM(sec), '' AS lay FROM my_table WHERE lay = '1863';
```

Also in case if column 'Shot' will be unique within a table as in example it will be possible to use next query:

```
SELECT t1.Shot, t1.sec, t2.lay FROM
    (
    SELECT IFNULL(Shot, 'TOTAL') AS Shot, SUM(sec) As sec
    FROM my_table
    WHERE lay = '1863'
    GROUP BY Shot WITH ROLLUP
    ) t1
LEFT JOIN my_table t2
ON(t1.Shot = t2.shot);
```

And here is solution which will work in any case:

```
SELECT t1.Shot, t1.sec, t1.lay FROM
    (
    SELECT IFNULL(Shot, 'TOTAL') AS Shot, SUM(sec) as sec, lay
    FROM my_table
    WHERE lay = '1863'
    GROUP BY Shot, lay WITH ROLLUP
    ) t1
WHERE t1.lay IS NOT NULL OR t1.Shot = 'TOTAL';
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the "format as code" button {} when posting in code =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
    SELECT     
    Shot,
 sec,
lay   
    FROM my_table
    where lay='1863' and Shot is not null
    group by shot with rollup

    UNION

    SELECT 
   'TOTAL' AS Shot,
 SUM(sec),
 lay
FROM my_table
 where lay='1863'
 group by shot with rollup
```